# Grails Oracle on Tomcat - JNDI config - error on InstanceAlreadyExistsException, etc

Tags: oracle, tomcat, grails, spring-boot, jndi

I'm transitioning from Grails 2 to Grails 3, and dealing with an issue in regards to the Jndi datasource for Oracle on Tomcat, with a difference between Tomcat 7 and Tomcat 8.5.

In short, with my Grails 3 app... I'm getting an error on Tomcat 8.5 that I don't get on Tomcat 7. With my Grails 2 app, I would not get the error on Tomcat 8.5 nor on Tomcat 7.

This is the jndi config I would always use for Tomcat to connect to my Oracle DB, which is referenced from my Grails app:

```
    <Resource name="jdbc/myGrails" auth="Container"
          type="javax.sql.DataSource" driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"
          url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION =(ADDRESS_LIST =(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521)))(CONNECT_DATA =(SERVER = DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME = local)))"
          username="USER" password="PW"
          maxActive="100" maxIdle="30" maxWait="10000"
          />
```

So when using this with my Grails 3 app on Tomcat 7... It works fine and I have no problems. But when using the same Grails 3 app on Tomcatt 8.5, I get an InstanceAlreadyExistsException, and the app doesn't startup. I came upon this page that details that error: 
https://github.com/grails/grails-core/issues/9424

One of the suggested solutions on that thread was to add:

```
factory="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory"
```

To the JNDI configuration... I tried that, and would get a strange result: I would get an error/exception, but the app would run successfully, at least the parts I tested so far. This is the exception I get:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Unable to load class: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver from ClassLoader:java.net.URLClassLoader@13221655;ClassLoader:ParallelWebappClassLoader
```

Again, even with that exception, the app does run correctly and connect to the database. But I'm concerned what effect this exception would have on the app.

The link mentioned above also suggests other solutions, such as setting:

```
spring.jmx.enabled: false
```

But before I keep re-trying different things... Is there a correct/standard way someone can suggest as to how to set the JNDI resource? For example, should I be adding the "factory" and then try to resolve the error that results from that?

To state some details of my app:

- It's a Grails 3 app, using Grails 3.2.8
- I want  to be able to deploy the WAR file for it to both Tomcat 7 and Tomcat 8.5
- It uses an Oracle database
- With the Grails 2 version of the app, I don't get any errors in Tomcat 7 nor in Tomcat 8.5
- With the Grails 3 version of the app, I don't get any errors in Tomcat 7. But in Tomcat 8.5 I do get errors, starting with the "InstanceAlreadyExists" exception

Answer (score 0):

From what I'm seeing on below page, I do need to set the JNDI factory property to org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory. The reason I would then get the exception "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Unable to load class: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver" is because it also requires placing the ojdbc JAR file in the Tomcat\Lib folder. It is new to me because I never had to do this with Grails 2, nor does Grails 3 with Tomcat 7 require it... It seems to only come into play with Grails 3 and Tomcat 8 (or 8.5) and onwards.

http://www.tomcatexpert.com/blog/2010/04/01/configuring-jdbc-pool-high-concurrency